# Object null after being passed on to a method

Tags: c#, null

I am trying to pass an object to a method. Before the call, I check whether it's null, and it's not. Inside the method the object is null, and I don't know why.

```
public class WorldManager : MonoBehaviour {

private Mesh mesh;

private List<int> triangles;
private List<Vector3> vertices;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

    OctreeNode rootNode = new OctreeNode (1, new Vector3(0f,0f,0f), 16);
    Octree octree = new Octree (rootNode);
    DualContouring contour = new DualContouring ();
    vertices = octree.vertices;
    if (rootNode == null) {
        Debug.Log ("Node is null"); //It's not
    } else {
        Debug.Log (rootNode.type);
    }
    triangles = contour.ContourOctree (rootNode);

    mesh.Clear ();
    mesh.vertices = vertices.ToArray ();
    mesh.triangles = triangles.ToArray ();
    mesh.Optimize ();
    mesh.RecalculateNormals ();
}

public class DualContouring {


VoxelModel VoxelModel = new VoxelModel();
int MATERIAL_SOLID = 1;
int MATERIAL_AIR = 0;
List<int> triangles = new List<int>();
byte Node_Internal = 1;
byte Node_Psuedo = 2;
byte Node_Leaf = 3;


public List<int> ContourOctree(OctreeNode node){

    if (node==null) {
        Debug.Log ("Now it's null");
    }
    ContourCellProc (node);
    return triangles;
}
```

To this point, I can access properties and the object is not null. The problematic variable, "node" is being passed without any problems. It is passed to a method in the same class, where it is null.

```
void ContourCellProc(OctreeNode node)
{
    if (node == null) // True
    {
        Debug.Log ("It is null");
        return;
    }
```

And now I can't access the object, it's null, and I don't know why. I don't get it, it has only been passed on. What is the problem?

Comment: Is the `node` variable accessible from other threads?

Comment: Can you produce a small sample that actually compiles and demonstrates your problem?

Comment: This code looks fine; something is going on in code we're not seeing.  Can you share more of your program?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: A new user has been given advice on how to improve the post.  I hope some of the downvoters will check back in a bit and see if the post has indeed been improved.

Comment: There is only one thread.
I added the rest of the code.
@JohnSaunders I did not know that, thank you.

Comment: Where is `ContourCellProc` being called?

Comment: are you sure you started the program and stepped through line by line something looks to not be either called `ContourCellProc` and or initialized.. also why do you need the return call here..remove it `if (node == null) // True
    {
        Debug.Log ("It is null");
        return;
    }`

Comment: Hate to say it, but this code still looks fine and it seems something is going on in code that we're not seeing.  Is this code a simplification of the real version that's showing `null`?  (Usually sharing simplified code is a good thing for SO, as long as the simplified code still exhibits the problem.)

Comment: As a diagnostic tool, try calling `ContourCellProc(new OctreeNode (2, new Vector3(1f,2f,3f), 8));` and see if that gets passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Check your conditionals - accidentally using `=` in place of `==` can result in a null object.

Also be aware that the code as given will pass a null object, just after the debug line - ensure you're not missing an `else` statement and that you know exactly what the branching is designed to do.

This can sometimes be the result of multithreaded access, if you're accessing an object contained in an object which is accessed by multiple threads - seeing the object is being passed directly and not by reference (`ref`), this is unlikely to be the case.

Comment: Also step through carefully in the debugger, watching the value of the variable at each step.

Comment: Checked all "=", everything is fine. The thing is that the object passed after the "else" is not null. Neither is the object passed in the second class. It's only null in the method "ContourCellProc".